# Hide a piece of a curve in ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting

I have such code:

```
f[x_] = x + 0.4;
x[t_] = Cos[t];
y[t_] = Sin[t];
Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1.2}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> 0.75], 
 ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {0, 1.5}}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> 0.75]]
```

and obtain the graph:

[image]

Could you help me, how I can hide the small piece of the blue curve left of the ordinate axis?

Comment: Use `{t, 0, Pi/2}` as the limits.

Comment: Thanks, but that is a demonstration example, actually I don't know which value of parameter $t$ I should take. Also I have several parametric curves...

Comment: If you do not give the plot range as an option to `Show`, then only the first specification of `PlotRange` is active. Therefore, If you change `PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}` to `PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {0., 1.5}}` in the first plot the superfluous part disappears.

Comment: If you in the Parametric plot will take the limits {t, 0, 1.57} you get what you need.

Comment: In the `Show` use the option `PlotRangePadding -> 0`. Most of your options should be moved to `Show` to avoid unnecessary duplication, e.g., `Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1.2}, PlotStyle -> Red], ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> Blue], PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {0, 1.5}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> 0.75, PlotRangePadding -> 0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `RegionFunction`

```
Show[
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1.2}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.5},PlotStyle -> Red, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> 0.75], 
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0,2*Pi},
RegionFunction -> Function[x, x >= 0],PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {0, 1.5}}, PlotStyle -> Blue,AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> 0.75]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Change the order of `Show`

```
f[x_] = x + 0.4;
x[t_] = Cos[t];
y[t_] = Sin[t];
Show[ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {0, 1.5}}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> 0.75], 
 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1.2}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> 0.75]]
```